# Error import javascript library in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want import javascript library. that is akarata library. I import like in suggestion in internet like this:

```
import * as akarata from 'akarata/dist';
```

or

```
import * as akarata from 'akarata';
```

still get an error like this

> Try npm install @types/akarata if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'akarata';

but I tried it nothing happened.

and the weird is. just first I type `ng serve` , because I use angular, the error appear. and after I make a bit change of my project and then I save it. I still get error but my project works. The library works well too.

Is anyone know why it like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript. TypeScript has its own syntax, function, and variables can have defined types, if you want to use an external library such as `akarata` you need to declare type definitions for TypeScript. Some libraries include typing file and you don’t need to install TypeScript’s type destination for them. But in case a library does not have .d.ts file, you need to install it.**[Type Search](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/)**

since your library does not have type definition (*.d.ts) in TypeScript and Angular

**Solution:**
Create if the `src/typings.d.ts` does not exist, otherwise, open it, and add your package to it:

```
declare module 'akarata'
```

and import it

```
import * as akarata from 'akarata';
```

Comment: Glad I could help:)

Comment: what's the subject in this phrase? "Create if the src/typings.d.ts does not exist"? i can't understand what it means

Comment: @netalex `https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/intro.html`

Comment: well @Vikas tanks for the link, but the question remains: What's the subject of the sentence  "Create if the src/typings.d.ts does not exist"? It's "src/typings.d.ts"?

Answer (score 2):

in your angular-cli.json file.

```
"scripts": [
    "../path" 
 ];
```

then add in typings.d.ts

```
declare var akarata:any;
```