# How to use external JS files in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I started a project with Angular but I never thought that install the most recent version of it would bring me a couple of problems. I am also using Materialize so when I try to 'import' its Javascript file it doesn't work. I don't know why, I was looking for an answer since the past Friday but I found nothing.

I have changed the angular.json file and referenced my JS location in it but it doesn't was sufficient.

P.D. I must not use the CDN for materialize JS.

Comment: You can import in `package script` or in  `index.html`

Comment: Are you using CLI?

Comment: Yeah, I am using CLI. I tried to import it in the index but it did not work

Comment: you can add `"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
      ],` in `angular-cli.json`

Comment: You can also have another way of adding materialize in you project. Check the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize

Comment: Actually I do not have an angular-cli.json. I only have the angular.json file and I already used that reference to my JS.

Comment: Ohh yes you are using Angular 6.

Comment: That's correct @RicardoLuna, angular-cli.json is for prior versions of angular

Comment: Versions: Angular CLI 6.0.7 and Angular 6.0.3

Comment: Please post the excerpt of your angular.json that incldues the script

Comment: "scripts": [
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
            ]

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CLI projects in angular 6 onwards uses `angular.json` instead of `.angular-cli.json` for build and project configuration. That implies you are using Angular 6.

As of v6, the location of the file has changed to `angular.json`. Since there is no longer a leading dot, the file is no longer hidden by default and is on the same level.
which also means that file paths in angular.json should not contain leading dots and slash i.e you should provide an absolute path

Install MaterializeCSS and angular2-materialize from npm

```
 npm install materialize-css --save 
 npm install angular2-materialize --save 
 npm install jquery@^2.2.4 --save
 npm install hammerjs --save
```

After installing all the required dependencies add them to styles and scripts array of `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
             
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
],
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
       "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js",
       "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
 ]
```

## For Angular Version 11+

**Configuration**

The styles and scripts options in your angular.json configuration now allow to reference a package directly:

before: `"styles": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"]`
after: `"styles": ["bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"]`

**P.S**
 `Additonal Info`: [**`Error import javascript library in typescript`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303509/5695162)

Comment: Yup, actually I have this: "scripts": [
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
            ]

Comment: Have you maintained the same order while adding it?

Comment: I do not know why the materialize.css works and the materialize.js does not. I used the same reference (obviously changing the folder css to js and the files extension)

Comment: try `npm install --save @types/jquery`

Comment: how can I add custom js file?

Comment: @ShobhitSharma try adding it in index.html script tag

Comment: @Vikas I knew it already, so it is not a solution its just like Juggaar

Comment: If anyone tried to import js to the index.html as a script, then don't use leading dots in your src path.

Comment: @ShobhitSharma do you found the solution of that jugaar?

Comment: Yes, I had added my files path in angular.json under build property. Actually earlier I was trying in test property that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

I think that key is: correct place on configuration. We have two places when we can potentially paste the paths for scripts. (Angular CLI: 6.1.5)

The first one is: (projects => your app name => architect => build)

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/<your app name>",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": { ... }
    }
```

The second one is: (projects => your app name => architect => test) - WRONG PLACE

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
        ],
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    }
```

After that you shoud have something like this on your browser:

[image]

I hope that it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

js always write in script tag with "".

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Vhls": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Vhls",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/videogular2/fonts/videogular.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/hls.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {...............
```