# How to read constants in .js file from .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've `Constants.js` file with below variables defined.

```
var baseApiUrl = "/api";
var ConstantAPI = {
  employee: baseApiUrl + "/employee",
  }
```

and I'm accessing using `ConstantAPI.employee`

I've `Constants.ts` as well. How can I access `baseApiUrl` in `.ts` file.

I'm trying like below

```
export class DataService {

constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient) {
    }

getEmployess(): Observable<any> {
        var url = ConstantAPI.employee;  // Error: Cannot find name 'ConstantAPI'
        return this.http.post(url, searchData, options)
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see the import statement for ConstantAPI

Comment: You can't import it because it's not a module. You have to add it the Angular config file as an external JS file, and then define it as a global type in Typescript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use external JS files in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842115/how-to-use-external-js-files-in-angular-6)

Comment: Why you are not declare global variable in environment.ts file . So you no need to create `constant.js` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is to reformat your JavaScript file to be exportable via `module.exports` like so:

```
module.exports.baseApiUrl = "/api";
module.exports.ConstantAPI = {
    employee: baseApiUrl + "/employee"
}
```

and then import like: `import * as Constants from "/path/to/Constants"`
or `import {baseApiUrl} from "/path/to/Constants"` to use them individually.

and then use like `Constants.baseApiUrl`
or `baseApiUrl` if the second way.

Comment: Did the same before.. Bit your answer is more relative. Thanks.