# Angular 6 : is it okay to use existing cshtml markup of mvc in angular 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, migration

I have a project to migrate an MVC application to Angular6. Now the designs are already existing in cshtml files i.e. views. So is it okay to use those designs as it is in angular.

NOTE : The designs consist of lot of images, css, js and charts.

I know the basics of Angular and aware about Form Templates and Reactive forms but styling them from scratch will take a much longer time.

So is it okay to use the existing markup of cshtml and perform the coding part in Angular TS components.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, the only time that takes is to splitting your views into reusable components.

Comment: where will i be initialising all the css and js files so that they can be used in html markup ?

Comment: move all your css and js files into the assets folder and try to add all the styles and scripts files in angular.json file. [check it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50842454/9640128).